# Animation not working in FragmentTransaction (Android)

Tags: android, animation, fragment, transition

I am getting more and more frustrated with a simple fragment switching, which for some reason does not play any animations.

The Fragment switching itself works and I can see my new fragment. However there is no transition.

Can anyone help me understand why?
Here is my fragment transaction code:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                transaction.replace(R.id.root, new InitialFragment(),"DDDDD");
                transaction.commit();

            }
        }, 3000L);

    }
}
```

Here, in slide_out_right.xml, the name is misleading - I've set it to something more  basic, to  be certain I am not screwing the animation params:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

Either way, I see NO effect whatsoever. I tried using setTranstition(FragmentTransiniot.TRANSIT_**ALLMOST_ALL_OF_THE_FLAGS**), nothing seemed to make any effect.

I am not using fragments via the support library, I am testing on a rooted, Galaxy S with Android 4.1.2.

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question: 
As I was not seeing just ANY effect on my fragment, no matter what animations I tried and wrote, I figured something more global was wrong. And the answer was stunningly stupid.

The blasted development phone had animators disabled via 'Development Options' in the Android Settings menu. I am ashamed to write how much it took me to figure this out, but hopefully someone else can benefit from this.

Comment: Wow, so obvious yet so elusive! I never would have thought it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of :

```
android:valueTo="1"
```

to

```
android:valueTo="1000"
```

and

```
android:propertyName="alpha"
```

to

```
android:propertyName="x"
```

If you want your fragment to move. I had the same issue with a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 under version 4.0.3. The Fragment on which I was applying the animation (moving in x direction) didn't move at all. And once I touch it (the Fragment), it refreshed and moved instanously to the final destination.

Comment: I know how to make it move. I was hoping to see just ANY effect on my fragment. And the answer was stunningly stupid. The blasted development phone had animators disabled via 'Development Options' in the Android Settings menu. I am ashamed to write how much it took me to figure this out.